# How to include library folder for compilation of classes

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am using `gradle` for a multi-project build. During compilation it is  giving errors because it is not taking libraries from local server and EAR lib. How to specify these directories in `gradle`. And how can we specify `JBOSS_HOME` from environment variables.

PBI: I am using `gradle` with eclipse and I have multiple jars to be included so cant specify each and every jars.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With local maven You can just use `mavenLocal()` under `repositories` section. For other questions it's quite difficult to answer - question needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    runtime files('libs/a.jar', 'libs/b.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```